# Getting errors with Node JS and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodes

i have a small question, I am working on a React.js and Node.js project, my project was working fine until I downloaded npm install atomic-layout --save

My command: npm start (use to work before the download)

I am getting this error:

```
react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My question is the following: Is this linked to the download of the npm install atomic-layout --save? Should I uninstall this npm package?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Problem Solved: 
--> npm install fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Try the following,

- Delete the `package-lock.json` file
- Delete the `node_modules` folder completely.
- Do a fresh `npm install`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `react-create-app`. It shouldn't be a problem that you install any other library on the top of that, but it seems like the `react-scripts` dependency has been removed from your `package.json`, can you check that it's still there?

Otherwise, reinstall the npm dependencies with `npm install`. If `react-scripts` was removed, then run `npm install react-scripts --save` to reinstall it and save it in the dependencies again.

Comment: My react-scripts is still there, what should I do In this case?

Comment: Then just `npm install` to reinstall the `react-scripts` dependencies.